# A Southern Hemisphere Contest

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Let's go south of the equator for our next contest, what say you?

I know, again we're focusing on a region, but we're covering the world slowly but surely, no?

And it's high cycling season down south. I know we have a few heavy southern users here (ie. [Mac](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/1588/mac), [heltonbiker](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/2355/heltonbiker), [xiaohouzi79](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/2460/xiaohouzi79), [Anthony K](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/106/anthony-k), to name just a few).

Are there any Southern Hemisphere-specific cycling manufacturers or media companies that we should get involved with?

Any ideas for a campaign that will help us reach out to more Down Under friends?

All ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I think a contest aimed at the southern hemisphere is a great idea.  We have a good number of users in AUS/NZ, and it's prime bicycling season down there.  And we left them out of the last contest.

Something for the UK/Europe area next? Lots of users there and they were left out of the last contest too.

How well did the numbers work out on the last contest? Try something different? Maybe instead of one big prize, a bunch of smaller prizes?

Do you have any leads on a local partner? Do any southern-hemisphere users have some suggestions for Sam? [Knog](http://www.knog.com.au/)?